# Why does the Hamiltonian vanish for $\int f(x,y)\sqrt{\dot{x}^2+\dot{y}^2} \text{ d}{t}$?

Tags: calculus-of-variations, hamilton-equations

So I have this integral
$$
\int_{t_1}^{t_2} f(x,y)\sqrt{\dot{x}^2+\dot{y}^2} \text{ d}t,
$$

where $x,y$ are functions of $t$ and $f$ is a function of just $x,y$. Also $\dot{x}$ denotes the first
derivative of $x$ with respect to $t$. I am trying to study this type of integral and look for
its extremas, depending on what $f$ is. The first thing I am wondering though is what is the reason for
its vanishing Hamiltonian?

First we have the Lagrangian $L = f(x,y)\sqrt{\dot{x}^2+\dot{y}^2}$ which is
just the integrand. Then the generalized momenta we get from that are
$$
p_x = \frac{f(x,y)\dot{x}}{\sqrt{\dot{x}^2+\dot{y}^2}} \quad\text{and}\quad
p_y = \frac{f(x,y)\dot{y}}{\sqrt{\dot{x}^2+\dot{y}^2}}.
$$
And now we calculate the Hamiltonian to see that it is zero
$$
H = p_x\dot{x} + p_y\dot{y} - L = 0.
$$
I want to know what is the reason for this? I think it has something to do with the integrand's independence from $t$. But I'm not sure where to go from there.

Comment: The integral's explicit independence of $t$ implies that the Hamiltonian is conserved, $dH/dt = 0$, so $H$ is a constant as you find: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noether%27s_theorem#Example_1:_Conservation_of_energy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is due to the reparametrization invariance of the Lagrangian.  Specifically, your Lagrangian has the property that if we rewrite it in terms of a new "time function" $\tau(t)$, then we have
\begin{align*}
\sqrt{ \left(\frac{dx}{dt}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{dx}{dt}\right)^2 } \, dt &= \left[ \frac{d\tau}{dt} \sqrt{ \left(\frac{dx}{d\tau}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{dx}{d\tau}\right)^2 } \right] \left[ \frac{dt}{d\tau} \, d\tau \right] \\&= \sqrt{ \left(\frac{dx}{d\tau}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{dx}{d\tau}\right)^2 } \, d\tau,
\end{align*}
since $(dt/d\tau)(d\tau/dt) = 1$.  Thus, the Lagrangian does not change under this reparametrization  $t \to \tau$.

The Hamiltonian for any Lagrangian which is parametrization-invariant is identically equal to zero.  A nice proof of this can be found in [this answer over on Physics.SE](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/449215/81133).

Comment: Gotchu, Thank you very much! 